# Can angular work inside of a CMS and only act as a SPA for a certain subset of my websites urls?

Tags: angular, architecture, content-management-system, single-page-application

I dont really have any code to show as this is more of design question. But here is my problem. Im working in an environment where we are moving towards angular powering our front end. This angular app lives inside of sitefinity and as it is done now it is NOT a single page application. We have angular controls dropped on different pages. This has worked with our cms, but it is causing problems for bundling because without angular router I cannot make use of angulars built in lazy loading support. So if you are on our homepage, you have the code for our homepage as well as our purchase page. This is not going to scale well. Without the ability to leverage this, my only other solution I can think of is that each CMS widget gets its own entry point in webpack, so that I generate bundles for just that one widget, and then do that for all of my cms widgets. I believe I could get this to work, but it will require a lot of constant webpack configuring that will be cumbersome for the team.

Im wondering if anyone has ever configured an angular app alongside a CMS where the angular app is a SPA, but only for a certain number of "pages". So for example, lets say we have these pages in our website: /about-us, /contact-us, /more-info, /quote, /quote-results, /purchase, /confirmation. My ideal end result would be this: /about-us, /contact-us, /more-info are separate pages inside of our CMS, hosting static content that marketing can change whenever they want without the need for any deployments. However, I would like /quote, /quote-results, /purchase, and /confirmation, to essentially be an isolated SPA. All of those urls on the server would serve up the same page and angular router would take over at that point.

Has anyone done this? Once I setup angular router is it going to block my ability to go from /quote-results (which would be part of the SPA), to /about-us (just a static page outside of my angular application)? Are there any other complicating factors to what I am asking that I havent thought of / dont know?

Thank you in advance for your time and wisdom. Please link my to any blogs that you think might be helpful / related to my problem. Ive looked into headless CMS a little but honestly I would prefer to not have to change CMS as that migration would take a lot of time and would be very high impact.

Comment: I guess Angular router blocks moving you to a static page since you're trying to navigate through Angular routing and not via `<a href="/about-us"` or `location.navigation`

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that you exclude your static page from the fallback to index.html on server configuration https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration